# Switching classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't make my code work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.openMenu').click(function() {
    $('#menu').animate({
    left: '0%'
    },500);
    $(this).removeClass('openMenu').addClass('closeMenu');
});

$('.closeMenu').click(function() {
    $('#menu').animate({
    left: '-100%'
    },500);
    $(this).removeClass('closeMenu').addClass('openMenu');
});
});
```

This block of code is supposed to make a menu appear when the div with class "openMenu" is clicked and make it a "hide" button so that when it's clicked again, the menu disappears. And so on.

It works only once: the menu appears, the div's class is changed from openMenu to closeMenu, but it doesn't make the menu hide.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: include html and css please

Comment: Your handlers are bound to what the DOM was the moment your code executed. If you change the DOM the handlers do not change. Each element retains its bound handlers regardless of changes made to it. You will have to delegate the handling to a parent element with `$('parent-selector').on('click', '.openMenu', function(){..});` and `$('parent-selector').on('click', '.closeMenu', function(){..});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.closeMenu')` doesn't exist at the time your code is run.

You could easily combine the 2 handlers into one, or use event delegation.

Combining them would look something like:

```
$('.openMenu').click(function() {
    var leftAmt = $(this).is('.closeMenu') ? '-100%' : '0%';
    $('#menu').animate({
    left: leftAmt
    },500);
    $(this).toggleClass('openMenu closeMenu');
});
```

I may have this backwards and  `$('.openMenu')` doesn't exist on page load (depending on state of the initial element) , just change the beginning selector if that is the case

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that event delegation is what you're after here. Instead of using jQuery's .click method, consider using the .on method, and providing your selectors there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".openMenu", function() {
    // ...
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".closeMenu", function() {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not optimized. Anyway, it won't work because you are attaching an event to an element that does not exist `.closeMenu`.

To attach events to elements that are created at any time (also after the page is loaded) you should use *event delegation*. In jQuery, event delegation is available through `on()` and `off()` methods. 
See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Here's the solution (not tested):

```
$(document).on('click','.openMenu.', callback);
$(document).on('click','.closeMenu.', callback);
```

This solution works because you attach the event to an existing parent of the target.

(I repeat: this code is not optimized and a menu could be done in better ways, but event delegation solves this typical event problem).

For more on event delegation see http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ or Google...

Comment: not 100% right, the element itself does exist, but not the class used in the selector to find it

Comment: Yes but practically it's the same. The DOM element identified with the class closeMenu is not there: it counts zero elements.